# sc:Image outputting raw field value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm having trouble where my sc:Image tag is outputting the raw XML field value instead of the `<img>` tag I expect. It's only happening on this one page, but the Repeater with ItemType is a pattern I've done on many other pages without issue.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.Web.TestPage" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSublayouts" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <sc:Image runat="server" Field="__Thumbnail" Item="<%# Item %>" 
                              CssClass="thumbnail-image" MaxWidth="250" MaxHeight="250" />
                    </td>
                 </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <image mediapath="/MyImages/three-column-body" 
               mediaid="{343C5D5E-94C8-4D9A-B8E0-C65F89C0C155}"                   
               src="~/media/343c5d5e94c84d9ab8e0c65f89c0c155.ashx?20140523T0953399715" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Has anyone seen this behavior?  I suspect it is something small that my eyes just aren't seeing this morning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<sc:image>` works only with the field that use `Image` field type.

`__Thumbnail` field does not use `Image` field type. It uses `Thumbnail`.

That's why the output is just a raw XML.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  I didn't even realize there was a `Thumbnail` field type. Thank you.